# Is it possible to use HTML spellcheck to return a boolean value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a spellchecker feature in an web application. I know that html spellchecker is currently functional for input and textareas. I'm trying to spellcheck elements such as paragraphs, spans, etc.

What I have in mind currently retrieving the text in a container, splitting it so that I have all of the words in an array, checking if the words are grammatically correct, using js to create a input node, append each word in the array one at a time, and enable html spellchecker. But that would only work if it returns something.

Is it possible to return something like a boolean using HTML spellcheck?

Comment: Don't think there is a universal cross browser spell check api. Might want to look into using a third party service

Comment: The spell checking is done by the browser and is not apart of ECMA Script.

Comment: If you implement your own spellchecker, you can absolutely have it return a boolean or anything else you feel like returning.  You have no access to the operating system's spellchecker from within the browser sandbox.